# In Sencha, how to download jpg or png files from server and store in localstore for use later

Tags: json, parsing, sencha-touch, download

For my Sencha project, I want to download few images from server and save in the project for later use. I plan to use the local store.

I understand we need to send image data file in json format. Later i will need to save this data blog in local store and while displaying convert it into png and display.
But is this possible in Sencha. I have not done json parsing in sencha. Am new to this Pls guide

1. how i will parse json for image data
2. how to convert data file to image format.
3. is there any better to achieve this.
   Pls comment.

Answer (score 0):

1.
One option is to server-side convert the image to a [dataurl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). It basically means you have to convert the image 
to Base64 and add the mimetype for the browser to interpret the data.

It will give a string like the one below, which is easy to manually cache in localstorage:

```
data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA[...]
```

2.
You don't need to convert the data to an image. The browser does that for you. You can just use this string as a source for the image.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA[...]" />
```

or in Sencha Touch using [Img.setSrc()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Img-method-setSrc)

3.
Transfering images using JSON isn't recommended, because due to the base64 inefficiency the filesize is increased by about [37%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402329/base64-encoded-image-size).
If the images are static assets, you can add them to the application by adding the containing folderpath to your Sencha Touch applications `app.json` file (see the resources and appcache property). This means they will get copied along when building the application.

more info: http://www.sencha.com/blog/offline-techniques-sencha-touch/