# socket.io binary buffer advantages?

Tags: binary, socket.io, base64, socket.io-1.0

Currently, im sending `base64` strings over my `socket.io 0.9` to send images around in my chat app.

I upgraded to `socket.io 1.0,` which in the documentation says it supports `Binary` data, like `Buffers`. I have little knowledge over what Buffers are, but can seem to get it work.

What is the advantage for me, would i move all my `base64` string into `Buffers` and sending them, instead of the raw string. Does the Binary support do anything smart for large messages?

Comment: I use base64 too but I experience some problem when the file is big, user gets timeout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734943/chat-message-is-blocked-when-sending-file-then-timeout-due-to-heartbeat            Do it bother you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

socket.io introduced the ability to send binary data mainly because users asked for it.

If you send an image directly as a buffer, you will reduce the bandwidth. Base64 is approximately 37% larger than the original data size.

Source : [base64 encoded image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402329/base64-encoded-image-size)

Comment: Thanks! Is it also more stable? When i have a bad (mobile) connection and sending a big base64, the connection breaks sometimes.

Comment: Reliability is a problem in case of reconnection with mobile devices. You still need a confirmation system to know if the client got the image.