# IOS send data to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, bytestream

I'm trying to send a image from mydevice to server use Socket.

I used this code to convert from image to bytes. After that, I sent bytes to server:

```
- (IBAction)btnSend:(id)sender {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
//    NSLog(@"data: %@", imageData);
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageData];
    NSDictionary *deviceDic = @{@"RequestType": @"5",
                                @"StringData":string};
    NSData* bodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:deviceDic
                                                       options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    [socket writeData:bodyData withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}
```

But, my bytes array is very big so, I want to send ever bytes to server.

Comment: Why read the `.png` into a `UIImage` object only to generate  a PNG representation straight away?  What's wrong with reading the file directly into an `NSData` object?  You are also certainly not formatting the data object correctly in the socket request.  What protocol are you using?

Comment: He probably means a partial content technique. what protocol do you use when communicating via socket? is it http?

Comment: What is `socket`? What doesn't work? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are encoding your image data into a String (base64?), and then encoding that `NSDictionary` into `NSData` and posting that to your server as a JSON object.

Encoding images into strings will always produce a much larger content length that the data itself in image representation (see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402329/base64-encoded-image-size)). So if you want to send less data to your server, you will need to find a way to upload your image straight in binary format. Not a big deal, just that your server's API needs to support that functionality.