# content-length much larger than expected

Tags: ajax, http, post

I'm sending an AJAX request with a few form fields (maybe 200 bytes max) and an image in base64.  The image is 770KB but the content length says 1.1MB....is all of that extra data overhead?! Is there a better way to send an image?

Comment: And when I send a 3.9MB file the content-length is 5,768,850

Comment: possible duplicate of [base64 encoded image size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402329/base64-encoded-image-size)

Comment: Base-64 encoded data is approximately 33% larger than the original binary data.