# Resize uploaded image to multiple dimensions

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I'm building my own simple CMS. Here is a problem with images. Loading large size images slow down the website. I'm here to ask how to resize an image to multiple dimensions for example: **image.jpg** orginal size is 1280x720pixels; for thumbnail to create **image250x250.jpg**; inside post usage **image500x350.jpg** and so on.
Currently using the same image for thumbnails, posts and so on. I'm just styling with CSS.

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Can you base-64 encode them?

Comment: @sburke0708 base-64 encoding images *increases* the amount of data that must be transfered.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402329/base64-encoded-image-size

Comment: can you create a div and set the background-image size and width in your css?

Comment: @sburke0708 im doing that right now

Answer (score 0):

After a user uploads an image, you'll need to create and retain multiple copies of that image on your server (one copy per desired size).  The `ImageMagick` software is commonly used for such tasks.

There are many explanations online that will go into more detail, but in general you'll want to install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) on your server, then enable the [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) PHP extension.

After creating a few copies of the uploaded image, you can use the [Imagick::resizeImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php) function to independently modify the size of each one.

If you're unable to install the PHP extension, then you can instead invoke ImageMagick's [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) command line utility via PHP's `exec()` function.