# based 64 image how to change height and width

Tags: jquery, html

I have this image with a plugin to screen shot page using url
and it creates based 64 image

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs%3D" data-url="google.com" alt="google">
```

and this is my plug in

```
    $(window).load(function() {

        $('img[data-url]').each(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=' + $(this).data('url') + '&screenshot=true',
                context: this,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    data = data.screenshot.data.replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/-/g, '+');
                    $(this).attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data);
                }
            });
        });

});
```

when I view page source it shows that my image is 320 X 240 pixels, how to adjust it to make 500 x 500 pixels?

Appreciate if you can help me find out thanks,
I search a lot but can't see solutions.

Comment: Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402329/base64-encoded-image-size

Comment: Hi use this http://plnkr.co/edit/MyzOXHEt26wKsOICeBDq?p=preview

Comment: @BrandonJakeSullano Should be able to get `height` to `569` , `width` to `320` by adding `&strategy=mobile` to url; See https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2015/11/google-secret-screenshot-api/. Could also try resizing image using `canvas` https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2015/11/google-secret-screenshot-api/

Comment: is there any bigger than &srategy=mobile? can I use desktop screen?