# What is the best way to load an image faster, either the .png/.jpg format or the data URI scheme?

Tags: html, css, data-uri, data-uri-scheme

Does loading an image in the **data URI** format, make it load faster in the page?
For example:`background: url("data:image/jpg;base64,/someImageData")`

Or does it load faster in the common .jpg or .png format?
For example: `background: url("wallpaper.jpg")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time needed to render the image will be identical, but the time it takes to load may be different. Base64 encoding an image makes it about [37% larger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402329/base64-encoded-image-size) than if you were to link to it via a url():

> Very roughly, the final size of Base64-encoded binary data is equal to 1.37 times the original data size

However, while the image is larger and requires more bytes to be downloaded, you save the time of a talkback with your server to fetch the image with the url() method. There's no way to say for sure which loads faster - it will depend on the connection of your users. See [this article](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/) on when it's a good idea to use base64 encoded images.

Answer (score 1):

Data-uri s are about 37% larger in size, but there is something more important:

[On Mobile, Data URIs are 6x Slower than Source Linking (New Research)](http://dev.mobify.com/blog/data-uris-are-slow-on-mobile/)

So be carefull with this. And, [as stated on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=datauri), IE < 9 has significant total amount of data limit.