# Image loading from server

Tags: android, image, imageview

Which is the fastest and best way to get image from server in android 
            app.

```
     1. Image url
     2. base64 format
```

or any other format which load image very quick as on normal internet speed.

Comment: use picasso or glide library

Comment: You can use lazy loader to load image on normal internet speed. You can also have a look on Picasso and Glide library.

Comment: Image url of course, less data than base64

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402329/base64-encoded-image-size) base64 format is %37 larger than normal image. So if you use base64 format, you will have larger image and longer download time. In this case, you need to use normal image url.

To download images as fast as possible, you can use  [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Answer (score 0):

Just use glide for faster image load in your application because glide uses caching of images and it loads an image after compressing it a little bit. Even Google recommend this library to developers , Google used this library in Gmail.