# Base64string size is too large in payload

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to upload big files as multipart, so I convert the blob to base64string (by dividing the file to 5 MB chunks), however when I want to send it to the API the size is much bigger than the real size, when I copy the base64string to a text file and save it, the size is about 7 MB but when I try to post it, the size is more than 13 MB!!

[image]

Here is the code:

```
private UploadFileChunk(fileName: string, base64Chunk: string, partCount: number,uploadId:string): Promise<any> {
    const dataToSend = {
      fileName,
      partNumber:partCount,
      fileChunk: base64Chunk,
      uploadId
    };

    return this.props.service.post(`apiURL/api/uploadchunks`, JSON.stringify(dataToSend));
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the effect of encoding an image in base64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402329/what-is-the-effect-of-encoding-an-image-in-base64)

Comment: Can we send raw data instead of base64? I'm looking for a way of sending binary to my api

Comment: Not if you plan on using JSON as data carrier. You'd have to revert back to multipart file upload.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any sample?