# What is a base64 length in bytes?

Tags: javascript, canvas, base64

I have a file encoded in Base64 with a certain file length. How do I get the size in bytes?

Example:

```
var size= canvas.toDataURL();   

console.log(resizeCanvasURL.length);


// -> 132787  base64 length
```

Comment: You mean the length of the file after you decode it from base64?  You have to decode it first.

Comment: Base64 - 5 bits, Normal chars - 8 bits => `size * 1.6`

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533113/calculate-the-size-to-a-base-64-encoded-message and (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715415/base64-what-is-the-worst-possible-increase-in-space-usage) (you will need to reverse those formulas)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each symbol in Base64 encoding holds 6 bits of information. Each symbol in normal file hold 8 bits. Since after decoding you have the same amount of information you need:

```
normal file size - 1000 bytes
base64 file size - 1333 bytes
```

Comment: Yep, for some short period I thought that 64 is 5th power of 2 :)

Comment: and how do I calculate: 132787  //base64 length

Comment: If you have a file of 132787 size in base64, then normal size will be 132787 * 0.75

Comment: your are totally right, sorry I didn't sleep for 2 days due to my stupid exams

Answer (score 8):

The answer from mishik is wrong.

Base64 is filled up with =-chars (to have the right amount of bits). So it should be

```
    var byteLength = parseInt((str).replace(/=/g,"").length * 0.75));
```

Comment: I've found a better solution: Convert the Base64 string into a "normal" String and then read the length: var str = atob(base64); var byteLength = str.length;

Comment: I'm not sure if this solution is accurate. I'm getting back bad results.

Comment: correct code example, should be: `var byteLength = parseInt((str).replace(/=/g,"").length * 0.75);`

Comment: You're right. There's one closing bracket too much.

Comment: isn't it Math.floor(parseInt((str).replace(/=/g,"").length * 0.75))) ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const stringLength = resizeCanvasURL.length 
const sizeInBytes = 4 * Math.ceil(stringLength / 3) * 0.5624896334383812;
const sizeInKb = sizeInBytes / 1000;
```

OR

```js
 const stringLength = resizeCanvasURL.length 
 const sizeInBytes = stringLength * (3 / 4) - 2;
 const sizeInKb = sizeInBytesNew / 1000;
```