# Image file size from data URI in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data-uri

I am not sure it's even possible but - can I get the image file size from data URI?

For example, let's say there is an IMG element where `src` goes:

```
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD...
```

Based on the `src`, can I get the image file size by using plain JavaScript? (without server request)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want file size, simply decode your base64 string and check the length.

```js
var src ="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP/// yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7";

var base64str = src.substr(22);
var decoded = atob(base64str);

console.log("FileSize: " + decoded.length);
```

Comment: I am pretty much sure the OP means the file size, not the image's dimension.

Comment: what is 22 in var base64str = src.substr(22); ? what does that number indicate?

Comment: data:image/gif;base64,  we need to exclude that 22 characters

Comment: @DanielTran what about data:image/jpeg;base64 ?

Comment: @AsheekaKP it’s not part of the image content. Just metadata

Comment: Noticed this doesn't work on jpeg's for me.
`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.
Error: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.`

Comment: You are a god. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

If you're okay with a (very good) estimate, the file size is 75% of the size of the base64 string. The true size is no larger than this estimate, and, at most, two bytes smaller.

If you want to write one line and be done with it, use `atob()` and check the length, as in the other answers.

If you want an exact answer with maximum performance (in the case of gigantic files or millions of files or both), use the estimate but account for the padding to get the exact size:

```
let base64Length = src.length - (src.indexOf(',') + 1);
let padding = (src.charAt(src.length - 2) === '=') ? 2 : ((src.charAt(src.length - 1) === '=') ? 1 : 0);
let fileSize = base64Length * 0.75 - padding;
```

This avoids parsing the entire string, and is entirely overkill unless you're hunting for microoptimizations or are short on memory.

Comment: This "estimate" is exactly right for my use case. I've tested up to 8 MB animated PNG images created in the browser, and it's correct to the byte for each one I've checked. Also, not parsing the entire string is a big plus as the images get larger.

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is to calculate the length of the base64 string itself.

[What is a base64 length in bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409496/what-is-a-base64-length-in-bytes)

You have to convert the base64 string to a normal string using `atob()` and then check it length, it will return a value that you can say is close to the actual size of the image. Also you don't need the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` part from the data URI to check the size.

Answer (score 3):

This is a universal solution for all types of base64 strings based on [Daniel Trans's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47852277/image-file-size-from-data-uri-in-javascript/47852337#47852337).

```
var src ="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP/// yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7";

var base64str = src.split('base64,')[1];
var decoded = atob(base64str);

console.log("FileSize: " + decoded.length);
```

Comment: you can just do `var dataStr = src.split(',')[1];` for all dataUri strings

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions make use of atob, which has now been deprecated. Here is an up-to-date example, using Buffer instead.

```js
const src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD...";
const base64str = src.split('base64,')[1]; //remove the image type metadata.
const imageFile = Buffer.from(base64str, 'base64'); //encode image into bytes
console.log('FileSize: ' + imageFile.length);
```