# Why canvas doubles the size of an image?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I was trying to compress an image from `file input` using `canvas`.
I read answers here, some say canvas makes the file *larger*, some use it to **compress** images, and since **I am new to this** :

```
function compressImg(img){
    var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width=img.width/2;
    canvas.height=img.height/2;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    document.getElementById("imagePreview0").src = canvas.toDataURL();
    const data = ctx.canvas.toDataURL(img, "image/jpeg", 0.1);
    console.log("size2",data.length);
}


var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    console.log("size1",file.length);
    compressImg(img);
};
img.src = file;
```

for an image that the mac says 1.7M , i get

**size1 2,318,839**

**size2 4,702,282**.

So - can you really compress an image ?

I just need to reduce file size to **under 2M** .

Comment: Afaik, toDataURL uses base64, which has more characters than binary by definition. That doesn't mean the saved image will be bigger as well.

Comment: toDataURL indeed larger but just about a quarter, not double. so it should still be smaller than original size because, still that was the goal. instead its doubled. why?

Comment: You may use this method to get the size of your data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47852277/image-file-size-from-data-uri-in-javascript

Comment: @enxaneta thanks, i tried and i get 3526695, which is still 1M larger and not smaller. Not sure what is going on here and cant find a proper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line:

```
const data = ctx.canvas.toDataURL(img, "image/jpeg", 0.1);
```

To:

```
const data = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.1);
```