Decoding images from a string
I am looking at a survey that somebody has created in Qualtrics.
At one point, participants take a photo with their webcam. The photo seems to be saved using a string that starts like this: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAACWCAYAAAAouC1GAAAAAX... [The string seems to be over 30,000 characters!]
I was wondering if anyone can help me convert this string back into an image?
Extra information:
The Javascript used to take the photo seems to be:
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  var newName = '③ Continue'; //Update - New Next Button label
  var nb = jQuery('#NextButton');
  nb.val(newName);
  nb.attr('title', newName);

});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() {
  const player = document.getElementById("player");
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  const captureButton = document.getElementById("capture");
  const discardButton = document.getElementById("discard");
  const uploadButton = document.getElementById("upload");
  let nextButton = document.getElementById("NextButton");

  const constraints = {
    video: true
  };

  nextButton.disabled = true;

  startWebcam();

  captureButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Draw the video frame to the canvas.
    var w = player.videoWidth;
    var h = player.videoHeight;
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 150;
    var renderableWidth = w * (canvas.height / h);
    var xStart = (canvas.width - renderableWidth) / 2;
    context.drawImage(player, xStart, 0, renderableWidth, canvas.height);

    captureButton.disabled = true;
    uploadButton.disabled = false;
    discardButton.disabled = false;

    // player.srcObject = canvas.captureStream(); // Not supported in Safari
    canvas.style.display = "block";
    player.style.display = "none";

    localStorage.setItem("verificationImage", canvas.toDataURL());
  });

  function resetPictureTaking() {
    captureButton.disabled = false;
    discardButton.disabled = true;
    uploadButton.disabled = true;

    // player.srcObject = stream;
    canvas.style.display = "none";
    player.style.display = "block";

    localStorage.removeItem("verificationImage");
  }

  discardButton.addEventListener("click", resetPictureTaking);

  uploadButton.addEventListener("click", () => {

    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("verificationImage", blob);

      dataurl = canvas.toDataURL(formData);
      Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('Pic', dataurl);


      var urllength = dataurl.length;
      var numvars = Math.ceil(urllength / 20000);
      for (var i = 0; i < numvars; ++i) {
        var start = i * 20000;
        var end = Math.min(start + 20000, urllength);
        var substring = dataurl.slice(start, end);
        var str1 = i.toString();
        var str2 = "Pic"
        var name = str2.concat(str1);
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData(name, substring);
      }

    });

    a = "Pre"
    console.log(a)

    stopWebcam();

    x = "Post"
    console.log(x);

    uploadButton.disabled = true;
    discardButton.disabled = true;
    nextButton.disabled = false;

    b = "Button"
    console.log(b)



  });

  function startWebcam() {
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(stream => {
      // Copy dimensions of video stream to canvas for still image
      const videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
      const videoSettings = videoTrack.getSettings();
      canvas.height = videoSettings.height;
      canvas.width = videoSettings.width;
      localStorage.webcamHeight = videoSettings.height;
      localStorage.webcamWidth = videoSettings.width;

      // Attach the video stream to the video element and autoplay.
      player.srcObject = stream;

      // Activate capture button
      captureButton.disabled = false;
    });
  }

  function stopWebcam() {
    const stream = player.srcObject;
    const tracks = stream.getTracks();

    tracks.forEach(function(track) {
      track.stop();
    });

    player.srcObject = null;
  }


});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnUnload(function() {
  /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is unloaded*/

});


It is an image, it's just that it's embedded using base64.

What have you've tried? Where are you stuck? [ask]. How is the posted code relevant to the actual question...?

What you have is a data URL describing a PNG image. To get the PNG out of it, decode the stuff after the first comma as base64, and write the bytes out to disk or wherever.

If you place that string into the src attribute of an <img> tag you'll see the image in your browser (if that's what you're after)

I guess you're looking at the result of that canvas.toDataURL()

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47852337/1427878
